# Text-orientation consistent for different browsers

Tags: html, css

If I load this HTML-file in Debians Firefox 60 the 2nd row of the 1st column ("test") is right-oriented. If I load it in Chromium 72 it is in the middle.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="text-orientation: upright; writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-align: center;">test</p>
    </td>
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2 Questions:

- How can I get it consistent in both browsers in the middle of the column?
- Why do I need to put it the paragraph? 
  It is absolutely not working if I have the style just in the td.

Comment: looks like a bug in Firefox...